# System role "Magento_Braintree::get_client_token" not found - Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, magento2.2.6, acl

Below URL throws the permission issue

`https://host/admin/braintree/payment/getClientToken/key/c21228d08eaede792c0256b56e18c861d90c4598adae24e63f6fcc8ea8325e0d/?isAjax=true`

> Sorry, you need permissions to view this content.

While debugging, I see the below admin resource in `vendor/magento/module-braintree/Controller/Adminhtml/Payment/GetClientToken.php`

> const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Braintree::get_client_token';

I don't see this role in anywhere in **acl.xml** and admin system role.

is this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it is a known issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13478